# JSON to PHP Array using file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get video urls from dailymotion. 
i got JSON results and its valid tested with online tools but when I use js_decode & print_r it shows warning like

[image]

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x49oyt5");

$content = explode(',"qualities":', $content);

$json = explode(',"reporting":', $content[1]);

$json = $json[0];

$mycontent = file_get_contents($json);

$response = json_decode($mycontent, true);

print_r($response);

?>
```

I want to get video quality and video url from JSON.

[image]

Comment: Check your `$json` after `explode` whether its in correct format? Secondly, why are you using `file_get_contents` twice?

Comment: Try to get `$content` once and just `json_decode($content, true);` you will get `array` then you can play around. I don't think it a good way to use `file_get_contents` twice.

Comment: Thanks it works. How to read json values?

Comment: Loop through resulting array e.g.

`$array = json_decode($json,true);`
`foreach ($array as $key=>$value){
 echo $key.'---';
 print_r($value[0]['url']);
 echo '<br>';
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using file_get_contents on what is actually already a JSON.

updated code, tested ;)

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x49oyt5");

$content = explode(',"qualities":', $content);

$json = explode(',"reporting":', $content[1]);

$json = $json[0];

$videos = json_decode($json,true);

//Cycle through the 1080 videos and print the video urls
foreach($videos[1080] as $video){
  printf("Video type:%s URL:%s\n", $video['type'], $video['url']);
}

//Cycle through the 720 videos and print the video urls
foreach($videos[720] as $video){
  printf("Video type:%s URL:%s\n", $video['type'], $video['url']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks it was a big mistake. then how to read properties value like 240, 380, 480 and url value ?

Comment: Resources are grouped by their quality, so you simply ha to access the desidered quality key and cycle through resources

Comment: can you please write some working code to access properties? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `array_keys($array)` you can get all the keys from array, it will return an array with the keys.

```
<?php

$content = file_get_contents("http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x49oyt5");

$content = explode(',"qualities":', $content);

$json = explode(',"reporting":', $content[1]);

$json = $json[0];

$mycontent = file_get_contents($json);

$response = json_decode($mycontent, true);

$qualities = array_keys($response)

print_r($qualities);

?>
```